# Selected option in onChange with react / redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm playing with react and redux and I can't do something that should be trivial in my opinion.

I have a component that is just a select with few options. I simply want to update my redux store when the user choose a different option with the selected value.
I think I'm pretty close but I can't figure out how to pass the new value to my reducer.

Here is the code :

```
const StoresList = ({ onChangeSelect, value }) => (
  <div>
    <select defaultValue = {value}  onChange= {() => onChangeSelect(???)}>
      <option value="12">MyStore</option>
      <option value="15">YourStore</option>
      <option value="18">OurStore</option>
    </select>
  </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    value: state.currentStore
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onChangeSelect: idStore => {
      dispatch(changeStore(idStore))
    }
  }
}

//connect is a function that gathers the store, the behavior and the view
//It returns the component that we really want to use
const StoresListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StoresList)
export default StoresListContainer
```

I put "`???`" in the code to show where I'm clueless.
As for now, the plugin chrome for redux sees my action but I don't know how to pass the new value of the select.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<select defaultValue = {value}  onChange= {(e) => onChangeSelect(e.target.value)}>
```